# Using JSON Object inside string.format()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have a Python3 script that takes an input HTML template and populates some data using this JSON and creates an output HTML.

Python Script -

```
with open('./jsonInp.json') as jsonFile:
    jsonData = json.load(jsonFile)

inp_f = open('brandedTemplate.html', 'r+')
htmlInp = inp_f.read().format(links = jsonData['links'])
```

My JSON File -

```
{
    "links" : {
        "one" : "www.one.com",
        "two" : "www.two.com",
    } 
}
```

Now using this in the input HTML like :

```
...
<a href={links.one}></a>
...
```

But this doesn't work. Neither does `links['one']`.

The JSON loading and everything works fine. I am also able to use arrays from .format function. Just can't find how to use this object anywhere. From `type(jsonData['links'])`, I know its a Python dict.

Is there a way to use this in a html template?

Comment: if you try `<a href={jsonData['links']['one']}>` ?

Comment: Almost: remove the apostrophe: `<a href={jsonData[links][one]}>`

Comment: Shoot... The apostrophe thing worked. Thanks @Jeronimo

Comment: @Jeronimo: Oh yes, I slipped on the apostrophes ;-) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jsonData` variable is a python dict. To access values in the format mini language you need to use `{my_dict[my_key]}`. Note that the key is not enclosed in quotes.
To fix your example, the html input should be as follow:

```
...
<a href={links[one]}></a>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [[Python]: Format examples](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples), you should use (templates like):

```
<a href={links[one]}></a>
```

as *html* format specifier (since [[Python]: json.**load**(*fp, *, cls=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None, parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, object_pairs_hook=None, **kw*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) returns a `dict`).

Example:

> ```
> >>> json_dict
> {'links': {'one': 'www.one.com', 'two': 'www.two.com'}}
> >>> href_text
> '<a href={links[one]}></a>'
> >>> href_text.format(links=json_dict["links"])
> '<a href=www.one.com></a>'
> ```